# Keystore cert chain wrong length - How to load entire cert chain into Java keystore programmatically for connecting to Kafka with SSL auth?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, bouncycastle, keystore

I'm attempting to setup the keystore for a Kafka consumer that's using SSL Authentication, and I keep getting auth issues. I have a Python example that works without using a keystore. So, I believe I'm doing something wrong with how I'm populating the keystore.
(Note: I can't just do it on the command line because the certificates need to change on a rotation schedule, so I need to automate this with Java code.)

Here's how I'm populating the keystore:

```
String cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "MIIEmTCCAoGgAwIBAgIUew1ANL9cTyhxLIo1ZpWLdKT4nOwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\n" +
        ...
        "fjv+XLmCfL1IKqcsEYmEPmyf5Knwk0mO7gtw1fg=\n" +
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "MIIFtTCCA52gAwIBAgIUe6eKhfms7ldZ78MxKiMzwFQNhsYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\n" +
        ...
        "jyDgNvJnm3g5eP6KUm9NNo7Le6lZoZhC3g==\n" +
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "MIIG5DCCBMygAwIBAgITKgAABSItHRkNBBF47gAAAAAFIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF\n" +
        ...
        "CF2TF5vdlOAUtvrJdnYgqNlSQHPAPeBP1runuwCV9ziZBTlra03cFw==\n" +
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "MIIF3TCCA8WgAwIBAgITXAAAAALRq61XLgYZigAAAAAAAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ0F\n" +
        ...
        "7ulMCI8RqFm3p32fs//+8o0=\n" +
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "MIIFEzCCAvugAwIBAgIQORoOm2GoxqBGK3xSM9br+zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ0FADAc\n" +
        ...
        "mBSMIdx3Iw==\n" +
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

String privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
        "MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAstlhsvxwbG8fVawH++HXq7mrqy9xfjIWwD45JAJSlstBBoBE\n" +
        ...
        "TovqdueB5W7DR0FVYoxmLj3vcG6fy/j9f+O9fb/mo94Ma39Px3I=\n" +
        "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

String rootCA = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        "MIIFEzCCAvugAwIBAgIQORoOm2GoxqBGK3xSM9br+zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ0FADAc\n" +
        ...
        "mBSMIdx3Iw==\n" +
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

final PEMParser rootCaParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(rootCA));
final PEMParser certParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(certificate));
final PEMParser keyParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(privateKey));

final X509Certificate rootCa = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()).getCertificate((X509CertificateHolder) rootCaParser.readObject());
final X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()).getCertificate((X509CertificateHolder) certParser.readObject());
final PrivateKey key = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()).getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) keyParser.readObject()).getPrivate();

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
char[] keyStorePass = config.getKeystorePassword().toCharArray();
char[] trustStorePass = config.getTruststorePassword().toCharArray();
keystore.load(null);

final Certificate[] chain = { cert };
keystore.setKeyEntry("privateKey", key, keyStorePass, chain); 
keystore.setCertificateEntry("CARoot",rootCa);
keystore.setCertificateEntry("localhost", cert);
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(config.getKeystoreLocation())) {
    keystore.store(out, keyStorePass);
}
```

While testing the keystore, I noticed that the private key (with alias `privatekey`) shows with a certificate chain length of 1. This is not right because the actual cert chain should have a length of 5. So, I think the chain is getting truncated like the code is not correctly parsing the cert chain into 5 certs but only into one.

If I append the cert (with chain) to the private key by running:

`cat pk cert > pkWithChain.pem`

and setup a PKCS12 record, like:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in pkWithChain.pem -inkey pk -name pkWithChain > pkWithChain.p12`

and then import that into my keystore, like:

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore pkWithChain.p12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias pkwithchain`

when I inspect my keys in the keystore like this:

`keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks`

the private key that I put there manually has a cert length of 5, but the private key I put there via Java has a cert length of 1.

How do I put the correct (entire) cert chain into the keystore programmatically?
(Also, is there anything else I need to do to setup my keystore correctly for Kafka? My Kafka configurations/settings have been validated as correct. The keystore is the issue.)

Answer (score 1):

First, your code doesn't compile after fixing the obvious redactions. It  has `String cert =` and `final X509Certificate cert =` in the same scope, and a reference to `certificate` which isn't defined. I assume the first `cert` is supposed to be `certificate`. Given that:

**`PEMParser.readObject()` reads ONE PEM-block**. This is why it is named in the singular 'Object' which is one, alone, by itself and not plural, multiple, or many.

To read multiple certs (in this case forming a chain) use a loop, e.g.:

```
/*final*/ PEMParser certParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(certificate)); // as already
List<Certificate> certlist = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
for( X509CertificateHolder tmp; (tmp = (X509CertificateHolder) certParser.readObject()) != null; )
    certlist.add( new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(tmp) ); // don't really need BCprov for this
// add { } if your coding style calls for it
Certificate[] chain = certlist.toArray(new Certificate[certlist.length()]);
```

Also, your `rootCA` appears to be, as it should, the last cert in your chain. Rather than a redundant copy you could just use `chain[chain.length-1]`.

Alternatively, rather than Bouncy's PEM-parsing, you could use JCA-standard `CertificateFactory`, which already handles multiple certs:

```
Collection<? extends Certificate> certcoll = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
    .generateCertificates( new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate.getBytes()) );
    // note Certificates with an s meaning plural, multiple, not limited to one
    // String.getBytes(/*nocharset*/) is often dangerous, but okay FOR PEM
Certificate[] chain = certcoll.toArray(new Certificate[certcoll.length()]);
```

PS: there are ways to run 'commandline' program(s) on a scheduled basis, fully or partly automatically, but that's offtopic for SO. It is also possible to run and control a 'commandline' program(s) from Java, but you didn't ask that.

Comment: Sorry, I mashed up a couple of blocks of code to create the snippet for SO. This is running in an Apache Pulsar source, and mixing in logic to run something on a scheduled basis won't work with how certs are being rotated due to issues with data flow interruption.